# Can you please explain to me what happens

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I would like to ask you what is the value returned when you pass the code 
('0' ? '0' : '1'), and i mean specifically why '0' is seen as true and what is the actual value that is being returned when you ask if a string is true like that, i know it can also be written as if('0') {'0'} else {'1'} i just want to know why is the string '0' seen as true and if all the strings are true if you have conditions like this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: provide your code. Also consider adding a good title.

Comment: _“Can you please explain to me what happens”_ – [ask] explains to you why that is a very crappy question title - so please go read that first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say '0' , you are referring to the ASCII Character '0' which is actually  48 when converted to `int` , and hence results in a true ...

Any value that exists results in a `true` in javascript `if` or conditional statement . Few values that do esult in a false are an int 0, boolean false, or an undefined (not undeclared) variable.

For examples below :

```js
var d;
if(d) alert("exists");
else  alert("d undefined");

d="a";
if(d) alert("exists");
else  alert("d undefined");

//if(x) // Commented out because this is an error because x identifier does not exist (declared) yet.

if(1) alert("1 is true");
else alert("1 is false");

if("false") alert("String false results in true");

if(false) alert("This won't be displyed");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped !